# Accessing Scheduled Posts in Unpublished Pages

Tags: facebook, scheduling

I noticed that I am able to schedule posts by setting the scheduled_publish_time field in a facebook Post.

I noticed that I am also able to schedule posts on unpublished pages. However, when I query the Graph API endpoint for the page, I am unable to query for any of these posts that I ahve scheduled that I have scheduled with the method earlier.

Is there any way to view these scheduled posts in unpublished pages?